# SQL Server error with Identity value when inserting row

Tags: sql-server

Weird situation here. I'm inserting a row in a table with a primary key with IDENTITY (1,1), but the value that it uses is waaay wrong. This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[adm_tm_modulo](
    [id_modulo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [codigo] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [descripcion] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [estado] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fecha_actualizacion] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [fecha_creacion] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [id_usuario_actualizacion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_usuario_creacion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nombre] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ruta] [varchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_modulo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Right now, it has 4 rows as you can see:

[image]

But whenever I insert a new row, the primary key ends up as if the IDENTITY value starts at 1000. This is what happens after I execute the INSERT:

[image]

I am certain that I have never inserted that many rows before, nor anyone else as this is a private DB in my own PC. Also, adding all the rows of all the tables, they are around 400 (not even close to 1000). And I tried inserting in other tables but the same thing is happening, only that in some tables it inserts a value from 3001 foward, or 4001, etc. It always starts with the first number after a thousand.

Any help about why this is happening would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is normal and expected behavior that `IDENTITY` values may have gaps like this due to caching.

Comment: @DanGuzman can I change the caching settings? I actually need them to be consecutive

Comment: "Needing" consecutive ID values is often a sign of a bad data model. Why do they need to be consecutive?

Comment: @EricBrandt this particular table is gonna be static and in the initial script of the DB. Other static tables will depend on this IDs.

Comment: If the keys are static and well-known, don't use identity surrogate keys. Hard-code the values. You need control so values are same in all instances of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a SEQUENCE object, which gives you more control on behavior of values generating.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Another option (which I prefer better) is to create an INSERT TRIGGER and define the logic you want in it